# Django send reverse lookup values with json values in api

Tags: python, json, django

I have 2 django apps which are related with a foreign key relation. The models are as follows:

**app1: models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from app2.models import Student

class Profile(models.Model):
    profile_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    student_id = models.ForeignKey('app2.Student', null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
```

**app2: models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from app1.models import Profile

class Student(models.Model):
    student_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
```

I am trying to achieve reverse lookups and for some reason i am unable to get it. I have looked at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) and [this](http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/01/11/django-patterns-part-2-efficient-reverse-lookups/). Here is what is what i am sending in my json from my `api.py`:

```
class studentList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        student_detail = Student.objects.filter(student_id = pk)
        serialized_student_detail = studentSerializer(student_detail, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_student_detail.data)
```

What i am trying to achieve is to send another field named status along with the above json values which would contain the value of the status in the `Profile` model. How do i achieve this?

Comment: I believe you can do student_detail.profile_set.all() to find all the Profile instance refers to student_detail.However, there is one thing I wanna mention: you will get a list of profile instance rather than one, which means you have to know which profile instance is the one you want. If you prefer a onetoone field, you may consider change your model.

Comment: In my app, there will be only one reference in the foreign keys. So if a Student is referred at one place in the Profile, he will not be referred anywhere else.

Comment: That is what I was guessing. So you can consider to use onetoonefield. And in that case, you can do student.profile. Of course you can give a custom 'related_name' to specify the reverse lookup name. Or you can do student_detail.profile_seta.all()[0], if you don't want to change the schema.

Comment: hi. thanks for the response. Can you tell me how to send the status along with the json?... I mean like how do i append the value with the object?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want to do. I believe your serializer is from Django REST API? you can check their document. However, I think you can still manually assign the status to the json. More specified example about what you need may help